# How to CURL an instance of OpenStack from another Instance

Tags: api, networking, instance, openstack

I have running devstack on my machine and created an instance of Alpine Linux which runs a Rails API (IP 10.0.0.6) on port 3000 (also tried 80, 8080). Then I created a simple CirrOS client instance (IP 10.0.0.4) to access the /test endpoint of the API. However, i find that I can ŕun:

```
 ping 10.0.0.6
```

from the CirrOS instance and receive response of packets. However, when I try:

```
curl -XGET http://10.0.0.6:3000/test
```

I receive the error:

```
 curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

The two instances belong to the private network and the security group policy allows any Ingress and Egress of any kind of protocol.

The /test endpoint works locally on the API instance.
I also tested that I'm able to make an ssh connection from one instance to another.

What configuration could I be missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

It wasn't a wrong configuration on openstack side.

I needed to run rails with the flag -b 0.0.0.0 to allow any IP. Rails on default only serves the localhost IP.

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try telnet`ing` on the particular port which server is running on to locate the issue whether it's networking issue or it is any other configuration issue.